# How to place TKInter Labels in batch

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to place multiple TKInter Labels based off a list of y coordinates

`y_coords = [0,1,2,3,4]`

Therefore, I came up with this code.

```py
for i in y_coords:
    label = Label(root,text='o')
    label.place(x = 640, y = i)
```

However, this only seems to place a label in the lowermost Y Coordinate.

How would I construct a function so that it places all of the Labels at once?

Comment: You put the five labels with just 1 pixel down, so the last one will overlap the others.  Try changing `y=i` to `y=i*50`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
y_coords = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
root = tk.Tk()
# Create a list to hold the labels
labels = []
for i in y_coords:
    label = tk.Label(root, text='o') #Create a label
    label.place(x=640, y=i)
    labels.append(label)
root.mainloop()
```

Just create a list to store the labels u created.
Also create another label inside the loop so that u can access each label individually.

Comment: How will that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do this.

> I would like to place multiple TKInter Labels based off a list of y
> coordinates.

I would recommend using `grid` layout.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
y_coords = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
root = tk.Tk()
# Create a list to hold the labels
labels = []
for i in range(len(y_coords)):
    label = tk.Label(root, text='o') #Create a label
    label.grid(row=i, padx=5) #you can omit padx
    labels.append(label)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Btw, you can add a string of text for `Label`:

```
label = tk.Label(root, text=y_coords[i]) #Create a label
```

Screenshot:

[image]